# How do I use a different proxy for each windows 8 app?

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-8-apps

I want to use proxy for 4 out of 7 windows 8 store apps. Unfortunately the guides I have found only show how to set a proxy for all apps.

I have windows 8.1

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: it's no possible in general.

Answer (score 0):

If the application itself doesn't support proxy configuration, than it relies on the OS configuration, which means just one proxy for all.